# Why $u=1$ is not a minimizer of $I(u)=\int_{0}^{1}u^2(2-u)^2dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to find the minimizer of the following functional:
$$I(u)=\int_{0}^{1}u^2(2-u)^2dx,$$
where $u\in Y,$ and $Y=\{u\in C([0,1]):u(0)=1,u(1)=1\}.$

The Euler-Lagrange equation of this question is: $4u(u-2)(u-1)=0.$ After solving the Euler-Lagrange equation, I obtained three solutions: $u=0,u=1$ and $u=2$ on $[0,1]$. It could be noticed that the solution $u=1$ also satisfies the boundary conditions.

However, the solution showed that the infimum value of this functional is actually $0$, which could be obtained from constructing a minimizing sequence. I was kind of confused about how could we know that the solution $u=1$ is not a minimizer? Is it a maximizer instead?

Thank you so much in advance for any hints and helps!

Comment: @Amr u is a continuous function of x

Comment: opps sorry. it was a bad question from me

Comment: This just like optimizing a regular function, $f'(x)=0$ isn't necessarily a min, it could be a max or a saddle point. Similarly, Euler Lagrange gives you stationary points, but not necessarily a max nor a min.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we Taylor expand $u=1+v$ around $u=1$, then we get

$$I[1+v]~=~ \int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x (1+v)^2(1-v)^2 
~=~ \int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x \left(1 \color{red}{-}2v^2 +v^4 \right).$$

The red minus shows that $u=1$ is a local maximum.